# Trying to create more complicated variables in Gurobi

Tags: python, constraints, gurobi

I'm working on my first Gurobi assignment at the moment and I have to create a transport plan. I received 3 documents (csv) with

1. orders (given: destination, services, deadline, type),
2. locations (given: x, y, type), and
3. trucks (given: trucks available, type and costs).

I received a basic code from my teacher and now I have to add constraints. The variables for this code have to be defined as follows:

1. `k(tr)`: indicates if the truck `tr` is used (binary)
2. `Z(tr, m)`: departure time of truck `tr` for its `m`'th trip
3. `Y(tr, m, o)`: `o`'th order to serve for truck `tr` in its `m`'th trip (binary)
4. `t(o)`: deadline violation of `o`'th order (binary)

For these trucks etc everyone can just add new ones so I cannot set a lb and ub. I think I have to work with loops but does anyone have an example for this?

Comment: What have you come up with so far? Do you have some code snippet or [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, please see this [post concerning homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Gurobi website has a list of examples that you could use. [examples](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/examples/a_list_of_the_gurobi_examp.html)